# Clear an environment variable passed through pdebuild

Tags: debian, environment-variables, pbuilder, pdebuild

I'm using `pdebuild` to test my package on older versions of Ubuntu. However an environment variable, `GOROOT` is leaking through to the build from my environment.

```
debian/tmp/usr/lib/gocode/src/code.brandscreen.net/cortex/go/util/http.go:4:2: cannot find package "io" in any of:
    /home/mjoiner/src/go/src/pkg/io (from $GOROOT)
    /tmp/buildd/golang-brandscreen-0.0/debian/tmp/usr/lib/gocode/src/io (from $GOPATH)
    /usr/lib/gocode/src/io
```

How do I clear this (and other environment variables) when calling `pdebuild`?

Answer (score 1):

Does putting

```
GOROOT=""
```

or

```
unset GOROOT
```

in **~/.pbuilderrc** have any effect?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, `pdebuild` runs `pbuilder` via `sudo`, so the easiest thing to do is to let `sudo` clear the environment for you.  The general recommendation from a few different places, including the [Debian pbuilder tricks page](http://wiki.debian.org/PbuilderTricks), is to use:

```
Defaults        env_reset,env_keep="DIST ARCH DEB_* BUILD* PATH"
```

in your `sudo` configuration so that you can still pass in a few of the environment variables that control `pbuilder` operations or are used by `debhelper`.